# Молоко жирностью 3,2 %

Tags: согласование, род

Если сказать полностью, получится: *молоко жирностью три и две десятых процента.*

А как лучше в разговорной речи упростить: *молоко три и дв**е** процента* (слово "десятых" опускается, но "две" ж. р. именно из-за того, что подразумеваются "десятые" ж. р.) или *молоко три и два процента* (согласование с "процентом" мужского рода, чтобы звучало естественней)?

И как сказать то же, только без слова "процента"?

P. S. Вопрос возник оттого, что в магазине женщина сказала именно в женском роде, а я как-то привык говорить в мужском, даже не задумываясь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На разговорную речь, сами понимаете, не все правила "высокого штиля" распространяются. Как сказала - так и сказала, значит ей так удобнее. 
Тут надо думать, из чего она исходила - и почему это показалось неправильным.

С первым все ясно. "Две десятых" никто не отменял. 
А вот почему это слух резануло - тут интереснее.

Наша привычка заключается в том, что дроби (а еще длинные числа) в живой речи мы передаем **цифрами** и двузначными (реже трехзначными) блоками: *3,1415926535... = три - четырнадцать - пятнадцать - девяносто два - шестьдесят пять - тридцать пять,* или совсем просто: *три, **один**, четыре, один, пять, девять, **два**, шесть, пять, три, пять...* Именно ***один*** и ***два***. Никак не *"одна (десятая)"* и не *"две (стотысячных)"*.

Отсюда, полагаю, и молоко обычно бывает ***"три и два"***, а не "три и две".
Но даму я бы поправлять не стал.

Comment: Так я и не хотел поправлять! Наоборот, я подумал, что, может, сам неправильно говорю. И когда я ещё на автомате сам сказал потом "три и два" (не так, как она), то испугался, что сам мог проявить безграмотность. ;)